# Cucumberish Issue : Step not implemented

Tags: ios, cucumber, bdd, xcode-ui-testing, xcuitest

I am doing XCUI Testing using the Cucumberish Framework. Sometimes when the test case starts it halts at the very first step

[image: Like this]

This is intermittent. Most of the times it runs seamlessly. I am are very confused what's going wrong.

I tried hard but can't get a stable solution.

Comment: Did this ever actually get sorted?  I'm having the same issue.